# Choice of XML parsing

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, parallel-processing

I'm trying to figure out what parser or more generally, what type of parsing I should use.

I don't have any prior background in parsing and the in the java project I'm working on I will have to: -parse several files simultaneously non of them very large, so far I have not come across any 1 file larger than 200kB. There are rarely more than 4-5 levels (Child-Parentwise).
 -calculate the difference in the files and display these. Using something like treediff or similar. 
 -Give option to merge the differences.

So my first question is wether to use a SAX- or DOM-based parser?
SAX seems like a good choice at first but I it seems like there would be a lot of tedious grunt work to get this working smoothly? Is there any good tools that will map SAX to objects in java

But since I want to be able to edit the document something like xpath/xquery seems fairly easy but might be pretty slow when saving?

Comment: Try to use an XML-based language (XPath, XSLT, XQuery) if you can. It will be a lot less code to write, and just as fast.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any upper limit in file size when these are viable? I have found a bunch of algorithms where these would suit my needs very well but I am worried that I might need to keep several trees in memory and I'm worried that it might not work. But it seems so much more intuitive (and fail safe) to work with a tree object than to save information and build a file from the information you kept.

Comment: You need to take care over memory management if your files are over 100Mb, but yours seem to be about 1000 times smaller than that.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'll be sure to vote this up as soon as I have enough reputation to do so.